# getElementById but unique for each component

Tags: reactjs, getelementbyid

I have reusable component on which I need to access its 'id' for scrolling:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
slider.scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft - (3);
```

The Id is declared:

```
<div
    id='slider'
    className="scroll-smooth"
>
```

I know this is wrong and it obviously fails whenever more than one such component is used, as only the the first component's slider interaction takes place.
How can I create a 'unique' Id (or something else) to make the id's truly unique to each object?

Comment: The component could just generate a new unique ID when mounted, and use that (assuming the scrolling takes place inside the component, or you are prepared to pass the ID out to where ever it's needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), instead of `getElementById`

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

const sliderRef = useRef(null);
sliderRef.current.scrollLeft = sliderRef.current.scrollLeft - (3);

<div
    ref={sliderRef}
    className="scroll-smooth"
></div>
```